# Python formatter "black" stopped working?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

Can't open an issue on github atm because I get a 500 error for 30minutes now when trying to create the issue.

- VS Code Version: 1.59.0
- OS Version: Windows 10 Professional 64bit 21H2 19043.1151

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Clean install of VS Code
2. Clean install of Python 3.9.6
3. pip install black (version 21.7b0)
4. Install VS Code extension "Python"
5. in VS Code set formatter to "black"
6. open project folder
7. open test.py file from project
8. save unformatted file with CTRL+S --> "Formatting with black" appears in the bottom corner but nothing happens

user settings.json

```
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

workspace settings.json

```
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "black"
}
```

It works when I call "black" via CMD --> "black test.py"

```
reformatted test.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

Already tried reinstalling VS Code / Python and restarting the PC???

Comment: Have you tried to create a new virtual environment or select some other formatter?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT yes, autopep8 does not work either but yapf works.

Comment: Could you have a look at the channel of `Python` in the `OUTPUT` panel? it will output the command of formatting.

Comment: When saving via CTRL+S, this is the output: > ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m black --line-length=120 --diff --quiet "c:\Users\Vega\Documents\CompanyA\2021\src\test.py"
cwd: c:\Users\Vega\Documents\CompanyA
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m black --line-length=120 --diff --quiet "c:\Users\Vega\Documents\CompanyA\2021\src\test.py"
cwd: c:\Users\Vega\Documents\CompanyA

Comment: I think I found the error: The project folder path where it does NOT work is "BC-9999 - #9 - [RC-9999] AF-Test Zipcodes". The project folder path(s) where it DOES work is e.g. "BC-999 - #6 - Company Costoptimizing Gross". So mabye the [] in the path name or something. Will update my github issue. /update YES, [RC-9999] in the path name --> black not working anymore.

Comment: VS Code github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16905

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I can not reproduce it locally, and `[]` does not exist in your logs. Could you attach a picture of the `Python` channel?

Comment: Problem is in the Python extension of VS Code I think. Therefore the linked github issue. I changed the end of the log path because it contains sensible information. Python Channel output is in the github issue.